# How to convert google result URL to regular URL

Tags: javascript

I'm doing some work with a chrome extension that needs to use the google chrome results URLs, which are redirects, and convert those to ordinary URLs for use.
Examples:

me Googling Google: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi6w8WR4ZzSAhUZHGMKHRntAv0QFggaMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&usg=AFQjCNFePWT_Lkni-D9ikX7wC3eYuDMQYQ&sig2=gPD7xuE6nstkxWFhSh2QLQ&bvm=bv.147448319,d.cGw

What I want: https://www.google.com

I've tried using string.split().pop(), but that just used EVERYTHING after the inputted text. For a basic example, I want a way to reliably turn testHItestBYE into HIBYE. What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Which `google.com` are you wanting? It exists twice in that url. Objective is not clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirect URLs seem to have target URL in the `url` parameter, so we can split the string using `'&url='` as delimiter, pop the last element, split it using `'&'` as the delimiter, get the first element. It is URL-encoded, so we'll have to decode it.

```js
var findURL = function findURL(url){
 return decodeURIComponent(url.split('&url=').pop().split('&')[0]);
}

//example call
result = findURL( 'https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi6w8WR4ZzSAhUZHGMKHRntAv0QFggaMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&usg=AFQjCNFePWT_Lkni-D9ikX7wC3eYuDMQYQ&sig2=gPD7xuE6nstkxWFhSh2QLQ&bvm=bv.147448319,d.cGw' );

console.log(result);
```

There are other ways to do it.